# Could a sentence with relative clause be simple sentence?

Tags: sentence-patterns

It sounds a bit basic and simple question but I want to learn if a sentence as the following can be classified as simple sentence?

> They decided **that it was a good idea to invest in the company.**

And if there is a special name for this part of sentence when a "independent sentence" , what I mean is that the part *it was a good idea to invest in the company*, follows ***that*** or is it simply called as ***object***.

---

Edit :

Another sentence could be as the following:

> I liked the book **that I bought last weekend.**

or

> It tasted so good **that I could not help but have another one.**

Comment: No, it is not a simple sentence. And that's not a relative clause, either. It's a complement clause, the direct object of _decided_. The fact that there are 3 clauses (because there are 3 verbs -- _decided, was,_ and _invest_) means that it is a complex sentence. Most sentences are complex. Simple sentences are rare.

Comment: @JohnLawler well I see what you mean, but this also makes me confused more. That is,  as you know complex sentence technically means that a sentence that has at least one  independent clause and one dependent clause and if there is a dependent clause , probably there needs  a  subordinating conjunction.When we look at the sentence, I cannot see subordinating conjunction.

Comment: @JohnLawler so do you think  the part   "that it was a good idea to invest in the company." is independent or dependent clause?

Comment: What makes you think there is no conjunction? What is "that" doing there?

Comment: "They decided." What? "that it was a good idea" For what? "to invest..."

Comment: Out of three examples, there is only one sentence that has a relative clause. Please edit your question title or delete two sentences that have no relative clause.

Comment: "That" is a word that can be easily overused. Be wary of this seductive habit. Many times it can be taken out for a less wordy sentence.

Comment: Yes, but they're wordy because all the signs are left in or those who need them to navigate the sentence. "Wordiness" is in the ear of the addressee.

Comment: (1) not all subordinate clauses need a subordinating conjunction. Only adverb clauses need conjunctions; complement clauses and relative clauses don't need conjunctions. (2) This particular _that_ (there are several kinds of all the little words; they're nuts and bolts, part of the grammar) is not a conjunction -- it's a different part of speech, called a _complementizer_, because it introduces Complement (noun) clauses. It doesn't do any joining; it just identifies the clause as one type of clause, optionally in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Could a sentence with relative clause be simple sentence?

No.

There are three types of sentences in English.

1. Simple: One independent clause with a subject and a verb (predicate).
2. Compound: Two independent clauses joined by a coordinator such as for, and, but, etc.
3. Complex: One independent clause with one or more dependent clauses. A dependent clause could be

(1) a noun clause. One example is a clause with the complementizer that:

> They decided *that it was a good idea to invest in the company*.

(2) a relative clause with relative pronouns such as which, that, who and whom, etc.

> I liked the book *that I bought last weekend*.

(3) an adverbial clause with conjunctions such as because, if, as, since and when, etc.

> I couldn't finish homework *because it was too late*.

As John Lawler commented, a simple sentence is rare in English and you can Google its examples.